# Getting content from custom fields of different pages on a single page

Tags: custom-field, pages

I want to get content from one custom field of different pages along side their page titles and I'm using the following code:

```
<?php
    $mypages = get_pages( array(
    'sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'sort_column' => 'post_title',
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'exclude' => '',
    'include' => '',
    'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' => '',
    'authors' => '',
    'child_of' => 53,
    'parent' => -1,
    'exclude_tree' => '',
    'number' => '',
    'offset' => 0,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
 ) );

    foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
        $content = $page->post_content;
                $new = $page->get_post_custom_values('new_file');
        if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
            continue;

        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>

                        <a style="display:block; text-align: center;" title="Download Now" href="<?php $new;  ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/new-file.png" alt="Download the File" /></a>


    <?php
    }   
?>
```

I'm able to get page title but not getting my custom fields value. Please guide me in this regard. Your help'll be highly appreciated in this regard.

Comment: all the cusatom post vlaues will stored in the post meta   so you need to use th  get_post_meta()  you can study more about this in wordpress codex

Comment: get_post_custom_values can also take a post id parameter to retrieve values from any post/page. <?php get_post_custom_values($key, $post_id); ?>

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
$new = $page->get_post_custom_values('new_file');
```

You must use:

```
$new = get_post_custom_values('new_file', $page->ID);
```

You must note also that [get_post_custom_values()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values) return an array, so $new will be an array. I think in your case is better to use [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) in this way:

```
$new = get_post_meta($page->ID, 'new_file', true);
```

Comment: Thanks Cybnet for your response. But it's still not working. I'm now using this code of yours $new = get_post_meta($page->ID, 'new_file', true); but it's not working. When I tried to echo it, it's showing different numbers instead of url's.

Comment: Please be noted I've place URL's in those custom fields

Comment: It is not important what you have set in the "new_file" field, `get_post_meta($page->ID, 'new_file', true);` will return the value as a string. Can you show the exact way you have used the suggested code?